# Read file in bash script with loop

Tags: linux, bash

Given file **socat.conf**

```
AUTOSTART=default

SOCAT_default="TCP4-LISTEN:3724,nodelay,fork,reuseaddr,su=nobody TCP4:your.wow.server.ip.address:3724,nodelay"
```

The relevant part of the bash script that reads this file:

```
[ ! -f /etc/default/socat.conf ] || . /etc/default/socat.conf

start () {
    echo "Starting $DESC:"
        maxfds
        umask 027
        cd /tmp
        if test "x$AUTOSTART" = "xnone" -o -z "x$AUTOSTART" ; then
                echo "Autostart disabled."
                exit 0
        fi
        for NAME in $AUTOSTART ; do
                ARGS=`eval echo \\\$SOCAT_$NAME`
                echo $ARGS
                start_socat
                echo " $NAME $ARGS"
        done
        return $?
}
```

For the full file see here: https://blog.bentrax.de/2009/08/26/socat-start-automatisieren-und-iptables-regeln-laden/

My question is, how can I add another command to socat.conf? I tried with

```
AUTOSTART=default,another

SOCAT_default="TCP4-LISTEN:3724,nodelay,fork,reuseaddr,su=nobody TCP4:your.wow.server.ip.address:3724,nodelay"

SOCAT_another="..."
```

However this did not work. I am not very familiar with bash scripts to understand the for NAME in $AUTOSTART loop. I think the answer lays there. Any ideas?

Comment: What if you try `AUTOSTART="default another"`?

Comment: @JoshJolly "second not found.."

Comment: Is that an issue with multiple `start_socat` calls? The conf/args seem to get read correctly: http://ideone.com/qP8aQH

Comment: Is there a reason you're using both `test` and `[]` ?

Comment: @JoshJolly solved, AUTOSTART="..", I was missing the ". Post your code as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for NAME in $AUTOSTART` works by splitting `$AUTOSTART` into words using the environmental variable `$IFS` as delimiters (default is space, tab and newline). Each word in turn is then stored in `$NAME` and processed within the loop until no words remain.

The solution to your problem, then, is to separate your words using spaces (or tabs, or newlines..):

```
AUTOSTART="default another"
```

The double quotes are necessary, otherwise it will be read as two separate commands, `AUTOSTART=default` and `another` (again because of word-splitting using IFS).